# Java - Initialize Variable on Condition

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a Java program to simulate the A* algorithm, and need to pass to my `a()` function two parameters, `initial state` and `goal state`. However, to ensure I have the correct goal state, I check to see if it's heuristic value is 0. If it is, then I mark `boolean goal == true` else I mark it false.

I was wondering, is there any way I could initialize a variable `State goal` to that goal state, by checking it's boolean value?

```
for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
    states.get(i).isGoal();
```

`states` is a HashMap of states for the algorithm, and `isGoal()` is a method that sets each state's boolean flag, depending upon its heuristic value.

Comment: Could not undertand your problem, but inside the for you can initialize any kind of object you want: for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
  State goal = new State();  states.get(i).isGoal();} Then you use the goal state object the way you need

Comment: For each state in my HashMap, the state has a boolean value named `goal`. In the above `for loop` I set each states flag to either true or false. I was wondering if I could initialize variables based on the values of those flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
        if(map.get(i).isGoal()){
            //instantiate wherever you want if goal is true
            map.get(i).setGoal();
        } else {
            //instantiate wherever you want if goal is false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your `isGoal()` return a boolean and set the `State goal` after checking the `isGoal` flag. i.e.

```
for(int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++)
    if(map.get(i).isGoal()){
        map.get(i).setGoal();
    }
```